# Adding annotation with a given value using Byte Buddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

How can I use Byte Buddy to add an annotation with a given value?

I'm playing around with generating test classes for JUnit and I'd like to annotate a generated class by `@RunWith(SomeRunner.class)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can annotate a class within the fluent API:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Object.class)
  .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(RunWith.class)
                                             .define("value", SomeRunner.class)
                                             .build())
  .make();
```

Alternatively to the `AnnotationDescription.Builder` you can also hand over a loaded annotation, the builder automatically converts it to the internal description format.

Comment: The loaded annotation can be converted by `annotationDescription.ForLoadedAnnotation.of(field.getAnnotation(RunWith.class))`